# Activating component CiviCase failed

Tags: civicase

I want to activate CiviCase in admin/setting/component?reset=1 and this results in an "DB error".

This is the error-log:

```
   CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: already exists"
```

[...]

```
Entschuldigung, eine Bereitstellung ist uns gerade nicht möglich.
DB Error: already exists
```

Comment: What version of Civi are you using and what CMS?

Comment: I activated it in 4.2 I suppose. Now I'm using 4.6.15.

Answer (score 2):

Solved :)

I activated CiviCase in the paste and deactivated it. Some sample relationship remained in the database. So deleting them is the answer...

Comment: The following relationship remained in the database:

Health Services Coordinator is
Homeless Services Coordinator is
Senior Services Coordinator is
Benefits Specialist is

Comment: Excellent. Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted one.